# Operate over all elements of a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, vector, range

I want to perform an operation over all elements of a column without using a loop but I am only able to add the first element of LagRank into the vector Significance

This is my code:

```
LagRank <- c(0.4,0.4)
low <- -0.25
up <- 0.22
Significance <- ifelse(LagRank[]>=low && LagRank[]<=up,0,LagRank[])
```

and the output is:

```
> dput(Significance)
0.4
```

Why only is added the first element of the vector LagRank to the vector Significance instead of the two elements of the vector LagRank? Am I using correctly the []?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `&` instead of `&&`; the `&&` operator only evaluates the first element. Also remove these `[]` and it should work.